S3 amazon java client. Need remove host for signed header
I use software.amazon.awssdk:aws-sdk-java:2.26.20, write code like it: https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/s3/java/
AwsBasicCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey);

S3Client client = S3Client.builder()
        .endpointOverride(new URI("https://endpoint.com"))
        .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
        .serviceConfiguration(srvcConf -> {
                srvcConf.pathStyleAccessEnabled();
        })
        .region(Region.US_EAST_1) // this is not used, but the AWS SDK requires it
        .build();

This code send request with auth like this:
authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=****/****/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=endpoint.com;amz-sdk-request;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=5f32718c77bcc8f909e23bcaa80f90ec61fb2b0f6918e4344f9401de32249c43

I want remove header host and url(endpoint.com) from SignedHeaders because they have not requirements (https://docs.ceph.com/en/pacific/radosgw/s3/authentication/#authentication). And I use custom proxy, this headers will be change. In amazons doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTAuthentication.html) this headers don't signed too.

You need to make a custom implementation of the Aws4Signer class to exclude host from headers( just stream filter out host)
.filter(pair -> !pair.left().equalsIgnoreCase("host"))
.filter(pair -> !pair.left().equalsIgnoreCase("endpoint.com"))

and then make S3Client use your signer class
.overrideConfiguration(builder -> builder.signer(new CustomAws4Signer()))


This answer not work, but you take way, thank you so much. I make:

use library com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-s3 because  software.amazon.awssdk:aws-sdk-java have final sign class, and I can not extend this.
need extend class AWS4UnsignedPayloadSigner, overwrite method shouldExcludeHeaderFromSigning.
Conf client:

ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfig.setSignerOverride("AWS4CustomSignerType");

